# Is there a way to configure a gitlab project to gitlab.com to ONLY use SSH and no HTTPS?

Tags: ssh, https, gitlab

For example I'd like to see this as a feature if it does not already exist.
Hence my question.

Comment: Ok downvote, but leave a comment at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be tracked with [gitlab-ce issue 18601](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18601), but for a private GitLab server, not necessarily gitlab.com.

See [commit cfd5870](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/cfd5870b62e9d76e564ffc64db1d1281b4a363bb)

[image: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/raw/cfd5870b62e9d76e564ffc64db1d1281b4a363bb/doc/administration/img/access_restrictions.png]

> When you choose to allow only one of the protocols, a couple of things will happen:
>
> - The project page will only show the allowed protocol's URL, with no option to
>     change it.
> - A tooltip will be shown when you hover over the URL's protocol, if an action
>     on the user's part is required, e.g. adding an SSH key, or setting a password.

Comment: Ax thanks VonC. I'd assumed so, just couldn't find it documented anyway. -- Cheers rivanov

Comment: lol, yeah sry super buys. TY for da feedback mate. Appreciate it. Cheers.